# Electron app, How to set the release server URL, only for download app update

Tags: reactjs, server, electron, release, electron-updater

I am new to ElectronJs and I am using [electro-updater](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) package to publish the app and to fetch app update. I have configured  as per the document and current the checkForUpdate method is getting an update from S3 bucket for now, but I need to change it to HTTPS URL so in future checkForUpdate method should call the URL and not the S3 bucket.